# Building 32 Bit Android Only

Tags: android, operating-system, building

I've been trying to build 32bit android for my Nexus 5x, codename bullhead, but I've been unsuccessful. Is there anyway I can force AOSP to build only the 32 bit system? I've tried using the TARGET_PREFER_32_BIT := true with not luck

cheers

martin